# Object function work first time but return undefined the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-events

My code works fine for the first time but the second time, my object functions returns undefined.

```js
_MANAGE = new Object()
//----------------------------- BG ------------------------------//
    var saveBg = {
        name    : "bg",
        url     : "AN URL",
        data : {
            ID     :function($this){ return $this.parents("tr").data("id") },
            name   :function($this){ return $this.parents("tr").find(".name").val() }
        }
    }
    
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//------------------------- SAVE FUNCTION ------------------------------//

    var saveButton = [saveBg];

    $(".buttonSave").on("click", function(){
        console.log(saveBg);
        var buttonName   = $(this).data("name");
        
        _MANAGE.saveButton(saveButton, buttonName, $(this));
    })
    
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//------------------------- SAVE BUTTON ------------------------------//
_MANAGE.saveButton = function(saveButton, buttonName, $this_button){
        for(var i = 0; i < saveButton.length; i++){
            if(buttonName == saveButton[i]["name"]){
                for(var param in saveButton[i]["data"]){
                    if(typeof(saveButton[i]["data"][param]) == "function"){
                        saveButton[i]["data"][param] = saveButton[i]["data"][param]($this_button);
                    } else {
                        saveButton[i]["data"][param] = $(saveButton[i]["data"][param]).val();
                    }
                }
                if(!saveButton[i]["success"]){
                    saveButton[i]["success"] = function() {
                        $this_button.children()
                        .hide()
                        .replaceWith("<span style='font-size:0.7em;''>Saved</span>").fadeIn("slow");
                        setInterval(function(){
                            $this_button.children().hide().replaceWith('<span class="icon-floppy">    </span>').fadeIn("slow");
                        }, 1500);
                    } 
                }
                _MANAGE.ajaxButton(saveButton[i]);
            }
        }
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//------------------------- ASYNC FUNCTION ------------------------------//
    _MANAGE.ajaxButton = function(ajaxButton) {
       
        var stringData = "";
        if(ajaxButton.data){
            var loop = 0;
            for(var param in ajaxButton["data"]){
                if(loop == 0){
                    stringData += param + "=" + ajaxButton["data"][param];
                } else {
                    stringData += "&" + param + "=" + ajaxButton["data"][param];
                }
                loop++;
            }
        }
   
        if(ajaxButton.url && ajaxButton.success && stringData != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url      : ajaxButton.url,
                data     : stringData,
                dataType : "text",
                success  : ajaxButton.success
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<!--THE TABLE --> 
<tr data-id="4">
   <td><b>4</b></td>
   <td><input class="name" type="text" value="A VALUE"></td>
   <td>
     
     <!-- THE BUTTON -->
     <div class="buttonSave" data-name="bg">
      <span class="icon-floppy"></span>
    </div>   
     
   </td>   
</tr>
```

Comment: It's working fine for me see: https://fiddle.jshell.net/1yttkt1t/